# Angularjs event re-registration

Tags: angularjs

Hi~ i have angularjs problem.

I really wonder angularjs evnet re-registration.

```
var test = 'test';
$rootScope.$emit('event', test);
var removeEvent = $rootScope.$on('event', function(e,test){
    removeEvent ();
});
```

variable  'removeEvent' is doing remove event.

i want event re-registration.

i try like this

```
var key = 0;
var test = 'test';
$rootScope.$emit('event'+key, test);
var removeEvent = $rootScope.$on('event'+key, function(e,test){
    removeEvent();
});
key++;
```

but it's not my want move.

i want re-registration event has same variable name 'event'

please tell me way.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear, but it sounds like you're overwriting the remove variable each time (assuming the code you gave us happens in a loop). So instead you should keep remove variable for all the keys in an array:

```
var removeEvent = []; // outside of loop to avoid resetting it
// loop starts here
var key = 0;
var test = 'test';
$rootScope.$emit('event'+key, test);
removeEvent[key] = $rootScope.$on('event'+key, function(e,test){
    removeEvent[key]();
});
key++;
// loop ends here
```